# i need to change date as sysdate and keep time as it is from below query

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

```
select count (*)
from LOGIN 
where LOGTIMEIN >= to_date('14/07/2020 15:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

i want the date part (14/07/2020) to be sysdate and time should not change. I tried sysdate but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get midnight this morning with `trunc(sysdate)` and then add on 15 hours and 30 minutes, either as a fraction of a day:

```
where LOGTIMEIN >= trunc(sysdate) + (15.5/24)
```

or as intervals:

```
where LOGTIMEIN >= trunc(sysdate) + interval '15:30' hour to minute
```

Quick demo of what those generate:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

select trunc(sysdate) + (15.5/24) from dual;

| TRUNC(SYSDATE)+(15.5/24) |
| :----------------------- |
| 2020-07-17 15:30:00      |

select trunc(sysdate) + interval '15:30' hour to minute from dual

| TRUNC(SYSDATE)+INTERVAL'15:30'HOURTOMINUTE |
| :----------------------------------------- |
| 2020-07-17 15:30:00                        |
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aab1304f23c14446114e84f028abac02)